# How .catch() handler is able to handle a rejected promise that is first in the chain?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I found this syntax confusing.

```
p1.then((result) => {
  // Promise fulfilled, handle the result
}).catch((error) => {
  // Promise rejected, handle the error
});
```

Here I am attaching a `onFulfilled()` handler to promise p1, but after attaching the `onFulfilled()` handler, the `.then()` function returns a new Promise, on which I am attaching a `onRejected()` handler. Then how does the `.catch()` handler runs when p1 get rejected?

I mean it is attached to the newly created Promise and the older one don't have a `onRejected()` handler. Shouldn't there be an error for p1 not having a rejection handler?

Answer (score 0):

The [.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) `function` returns a promise. This promise has a [.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method that is scheduled to be executed when the promise for which you called it is rejected.

In general, in Javascript you can specify so-called callback functions, that is, functions to be executed when some event finishes. This is a way to nonblockingly say that when something happens, then you want to execute your `function`. So, you pass a `function` to the `.catch()` of a promise and that `function` is scheduled to run when the promise is rejected.

Comment: I think the task of .catch() function is to attach a rejection handler to associated promise which executed by the reject() callback. So the .catch() function itself run with the synchronous code while the handler runs asynchronously. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @regihex you are correct. Your handler is created synchronously and will only be triggered when/if the promise to which it was attached is rejected.